# Controlling the baseline position of a fraction numerator in a notebook style?

Tags: notebooks, formatting

I'm using a built-in Notebook style "Equation" from the "Book/Textbook.nb" stylesheet. When entering fractions, the space between the bottom of the text in the numerator and the fraction line is too large.

I've searched the Option Inspector and haven't found a way to reduce that spacing. The documentation for FractionBox does mention that the axis of the FractionBox is goes through the fraction line and "the baseline lies below the axis by the distance between the axis and the bottom of characters such as ( in the current font", but I haven't found a way to make use of that information.

I know I could wrap the fraction in an AdjustmentBox and shift baselines, but since my Notebook will have many fractions in many Equation cells, I would like to set the Equation style to automatically reduce that gap.

Is there a way to do this using the Option Inspector?